# Which way is better writing a register path in Verilog

Tags: verilog

**solution 1**

```
reg q;
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
if (!rst_n)
  q <= 1'b0;
else
  if (en_a)
    q <= da;
  else if (en_b)
    q <= db;
  else if (en_c)
    q <= dc;
```

**solution2**

```
reg qw, qr;
always @(*)
if (en_a)
  qw = da;
else if (en_b)
  qw = db;
else if (en_c)
  qw = dc;

always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
if (!rst_n)
  qr <= 1'b0;
else
  qr <= qw;
```

I use `solution 1` a lot and I can find it a lot in many other engineers' code. `Solution 2` seperates the combinational logic part and sequencial logic part, the classic FSM style.

My question is, (for `solution 2`)is there an actual advantage over `solution 1`? And what is the difference between two solutions?

Comment: In solution 2 you need `else qw = qr;` for the two codes to be equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

It partly depends on the size of the design and the synthesizer. For large FSM designs a two always block approach uses less area, often has better timing, and fewer lines of code then its equivalent one always block. [This paper](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2003SJ_SystemVerilogFSM.pdf) from Cliff Cummings goes into detail on the differences between the one, two, three always block approaches. He been recommending this style for a while in some older papers [here](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG1998SJ_FSM.pdf) and [here](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsICU2002_FSMFundamentals.pdf). Several years a go my team compared the styles with our own code and tools; we can came to the same conclusion as Cliff. You should try comparing on your own.

The two always block advantages are:

- See the next value of the flop before the clock in a waveform or display statement. With one always block you need to calculate the values.
- Will not accidentally create an unintended flip-flop

  - Note: there is a risk of inferring an unintended latch, however since there are few intended latches in the design they are easy to spot in the reports of linting and synthesis tools. Unintended flip-flop are harder to spot.
- All the combinational logic is grouped together.
- Easier manual ECO. Usually fewer lines of code to change.
- No need to worry about accidentally mixing blocking and non-blocking
- For large designs:

  - Few lines of code
  - Smaller area
  - Better timing

The one always block advantages are:

- Generally one always block is *slightly* more simulation-efficient than the two always block - ([Cliff SNUG1998SJ FSM](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG1998SJ_FSM.pdf), page 10)
- Will not accidentally infer an unintended latch
- When strictly following IEEE1364-1995:

  - `@(*)` was added in IEEE1364-2001. In IEEE1364-1995, every signal external driving signal used in the combinational always block needed to be listed in the sensitively list.

    - Example: `@(en_a or en_b or en_c or da or db or dc or qr)`
- For small designs:

  - Only one block to look at

Comment: Another point to consider: one always block will *generally* simulate faster than the two always block style.

Comment: @Chiggs, according to page 10 of [this paper](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG1998SJ_FSM.pdf) Generally one always block is _slightly_ more simulation-efficient than the two always block.