# How to write a verilog code in two-always-block style with multiple state regs?

Tags: verilog

I'm a begginer of Verilog. I read a several materials about recommended Verilog coding styles like [this paper](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2003SJ_SystemVerilogFSM.pdf) and [stackoverflow's questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360645/which-way-is-better-writing-a-register-path-in-verilog/25369097#25369097).
Now, I learned from them that "two always block style" is recommended; separate a code into two parts, one is a combinational block that modifies `next`, and the another is a sequential block that assigns it to `state` reg like this.

```
reg [1:0] state, next;

always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
    if (!rst_n)
        state <= IDLE;
    else
        state <= next;

 always @(state or go or ws) begin
     next = 'bx;
     rd = 1'b0;
     ds = 1'b0;
    case (state)
        IDLE : if (go) next = READ;
               else next = IDLE;
 ...
```

And here is my question. All example codes I found have only one pair of registers named `state` and `next`.
 However, if there are multiple regs that preserve some kinds of state, how should I write codes in this `state`-and-`next` style?
Preparing `next` regs corresponding to each of them looks a little redundant because all regs will be doubled.

For instance, please look at an UART sender code of RS232c I wrote below.
It needed `wait_count`, `state` and `send_buf` as `state` regs. So, I wrote corresponding `wait_count_next`, `state_next` and `send_buf_next` as `next` for a combinational block. This looks a bit redundant and troublesome to me. Is there other proper way?

```
module uart_sender #(
    parameter clock = 50_000_000,
    parameter baudrate = 9600
) (
    input clk,
    input go,
    input [7:0] data,
    output tx,
    output ready
);

parameter wait_time = clock / baudrate;

parameter send_ready = 10'b0000000000,
        send_start = 10'b0000000001,
        send_stop  = 10'b1000000000;

reg [31:0] wait_count = wait_time,
        wait_count_next = wait_time;
reg [9:0] state = send_ready,
        state_next  = send_ready;
reg [8:0] send_buf = 9'b111111111,
        send_buf_next = 9'b111111111;

always @(posedge clk) begin
    state <= state_next;
    wait_count <= wait_count_next;
    send_buf <= send_buf_next;
end

always @(*) begin
    state_next = state;
    wait_count_next = wait_count;
    send_buf_next = send_buf;
    case (state)
        send_ready: begin
            if (go == 1) begin
                state_next = send_start;
                wait_count_next = wait_time;
                send_buf_next = {data, 1'b0};
            end
        end
        default: begin
            if (wait_count == 0) begin
                if (state == send_stop)
                    state_next = send_ready;
                else
                    state_next = {state[8:0], 1'b0};
                wait_count_next = wait_time;
                send_buf_next = {1'b1, send_buf[8:1]};
            end
            else begin
                wait_count_next = wait_count - 1;
            end
        end
    endcase
end

assign tx = send_buf[0];
assign ready = state == send_ready;

endmodule
```

Comment: The basic idea of this is to split logic in 2 parts combinational and sequentional. First of all there is no real need in just 2 always blocks. you can have more, i.e. multiple always blocks could represent your combinatioal logic part. Also, there is no need to flop absolutely all signals. If you build a state machine, you just need to flop its inputs or outputs. There is no need to flop other intermediate signals.  Some designs might require that you flop inputs or outputs of the module. So,  it is up to you to decide where to place those flops.

Answer (score 1):

I think you did a good job and correctly flopped the variables. The issue is that without flops you would have a loop. i.e. if you write something like the following, the simulation will loop and silicon will probably burn out:

```
 always_comb wait_count = wait_count - 1;
```

So, you need to stage this by inserting a flop:

```
 always_ff @(posedge clk)
    wait_count <= wait_count - 1;
```

Or in your case you you used an intermediate `wait_count_next` which is a good style:

```
 always_ff @(posedge clk)
    wait_count_next <= wait_count;
 always_comb
    wait_count = wait_count_next;
```

You might or might not have an issue with the last assignments. Which version of the signals you want to assign to `tx` and `ready`? the flopped one or not?

And yes, you can split theses blocks in multiple blocks, but in this case there seems to be no need.

And yes, the other style would be write everything in a single flop always block. But this will reduce readability, will be more prone to your errors and might have synthesis issues.